# Java AES-128 ECB encryption

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I have received a message from AT5 (Atrack)  unite encoded with AES-128 ECB encryption and this is the key in hex (`33333838000000000000000000000000`)
the original key is in string "3388"
and this is the cipher that i received but i convert it to hex

Whenever I try to decrypt the message, I face this exception:

> Error while decrypting: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Here is my code:

```
    orginalString 

 ?U??????}MgD?R???`????
#?j????g:N???@???$=???r?u?>~??Qh,?N?????3?8:?-E??;?b<J??I?v{?'o?m[?|?CY?n????K????>?ã??<?,????  ??f?'???}&?}?7r%??93??!u?0D?3Ig|??%'????*??`?Y^?M?4J?I?>?tIu???;?RR;2??{nrl??us
?R?F?oi????



String strToDecrypt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
secretKey = new SecretKeySpec("33333838000000000000000000000000".getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
byte[] cipherResult = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt));
```

Comment: share the code of how strToDecrypt is generated. Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt) would result in a byte array of size 900. 900 has 4 remaining when divided by 16.

Comment: it's being generated from hardware device we only control the key which is "3388"

Answer (score 1):

Your `strToDecrypt` seems to be **hex encoded**, not **base64 encoded** .. so you need to hex decode it before decrypting, instead of base64 decoding. But actually you encrypted data if hex decoded, would also end up having an invalid size. Your hex string is 1200 hex chars = 600 bytes = 37.5 AES blocks of 16 bytes .. Something seems to be wrong with your data ..

Also, your key is also Hex encoded, so you need to hex decode it .. not just do a `getBytes(..)`.

Comment: just because a string contains characters allowed in base 16(hexadecimal) does not mean it has to be hex decoded(you proved it yourself that it doesn't make any sense if it was supposed to either) also having a key length of 32 bytes has nothing wrong with it(neither has containing hex characters within key bytes) so we can just call getbytes.

Comment: @kamyarhaqqani: 1) Since it is supposedly cipher and hundred of bytes long, yeah, it basically does prove its hex-encoded; 2) Since he says he's using AES**128**, then, yeah, the key is hex-encoded also, but 3) much of the hex-encoded cipher is too non-random to be cipher anyways.

Comment: @kamyarhaqqani I wrote that it SEEMS to be hex ..I chose that wording on purpose to counter this kind of pedantic discussions. As for the key, OP explicit claims in the question that it's in hex, and the length of this hex key matches exactly the 128 bit key length needed for the AES-128 - also stated in the question.

Comment: you are right about the key and this discussion being pedantic. by saying "you need to hex decode it before decryption" you are actually concluding that any string which contains base 16 allowed chars(and 'seems' to be hex) is always a hex encoded string, it is not!

Comment: for the key they use string "3388" and i convert it to hex to get its 16 bytes

Comment: and the cipher received the encrypted message started after the second "2C" 
however i try also to decrypt it get the same exception